# Hide The Window Name In Titanium Studio

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile

this may be stupid but i don't understand. the easiest code ever :

```
var  fenetreBase = Titanium.UI.createWindow({fullscreen:true,backgroundColor:"white"});

fenetreBase.open();
```

whenever, this piece of code don't "hide" the name of your appli (which is in the grey "header");
Is it because i'm runing the programm on a emulator? or we can't just hide it maybe? (using android 4.0.3 currently)

thinqs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    fullscreen:true,
    navBarHidden:true,
    backgroundColor: 'white'
});
```